# Filter parents by child attribute, but eager-load all children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

That title is a bit obtuse, so here's an example. Suppose we have a Rails 3 app with models `Ship`, `Pirate`, and `Parrot`. A ship has_many pirates, and a pirate has_many parrots.

`Ship.includes(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name LIKE ?', '%polly%')`

This returns ships having at least one pirate with at least one parrot whose name is like "polly". I would also like it to **eager-load all of the pirates and parrots** for those ships... but in reality only the pirates with matching parrots are eager-loaded, and among those, only the matching parrots are eager-loaded. The generated SQL is something like this:

`SELECT ships.id AS t0_r0, ships.name AS t0_r1, pirates.id AS t1_r0, pirates.name AS t1_r1, parrots.id AS t2_r0, parrots.name AS t2_r1 FROM ships LEFT OUTER JOIN pirates ON pirates.ship_id = ships.id LEFT OUTER JOIN parrots ON parrots.pirate_id = pirates.id WHERE (parrots.name LIKE '%polly%')`

When doing `Ship.includes(pirates: :parrots)` without the condition, ActiveRecord generates a bundle of queries that is somewhat closer to what I want:

```
SELECT ships.* FROM ships
SELECT pirates.* FROM pirates WHERE pirates.ship_id IN (ship IDs from previous query)
SELECT parrots.* FROM parrots WHERE parrots.pirate_id IN (pirate IDs from previous query)
```

If I could somehow change that first query to use the SQL from the first example, it would do exactly what I want:

```
SELECT ships.* FROM ships LEFT OUTER JOIN pirates ON pirates.ship_id = ships.id LEFT OUTER JOIN parrots ON parrots.pirate_id = pirates.id WHERE (parrots.name LIKE '%polly%')
SELECT pirates.* FROM pirates WHERE pirates.ship_id IN (ship IDs from previous query)
SELECT parrots.* FROM parrots WHERE parrots.pirate_id IN (pirate IDs from previous query)
```

But I'm not aware of any way to get ActiveRecord to do this, or any way to do it myself and "manually" wire up the eager-loading (which is necessary in my situation to avoid an N+1 query explosion). Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ship.joins(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name LIKE ?', '%polly%').preload(pirates: :parrots)
```

requires rails 3+

Answer (score 0):

If INNER JOIN is what you're looking for, I think

```
Ship.includes(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name LIKE ?', '%polly%').joins(pirates: :parrots)
```

gets it done.

Comment: This generates the same single SQL statement as my first example, but with LEFT OUTER JOIN replaced with INNER JOIN. In this case the result is the same, though in my real app it's actually worse because I'm eager-loading associations that are not used in the `where` clause, and I don't want to exclude models that lack those associations from the results. I will update the question to clarify this.

Comment: Ugly, but `Ship.includes(pirates: :parrots).where('ships.id IN (?)', Ship.select('id').includes(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name LIKE ?', '%polly%'))`

Comment: I just arrived at this same workaround myself. Unfortunately the `includes` seems to override the `select` when used with `where`, loading up every attribute of every included model as it normally would (and using `pluck` instead generates an invalid query). This doesn't bode well for my memory usage and time-spent-in-ActiveRecord per request, though it technically solves the problem and avoids N+1. Should I mark this as answered?

Comment: That's odd. For me the generated sql is `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "ships"."id") FROM "ships" LEFT OUTER JOIN "pirates" on "pirates"."ship_id" = "ships"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "parrots" on "parrots"."pirate_id" = "pirates"."id" WHERE (parrots.name LIKE '%polly%')` - are you getting something different, or is that not what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure why that extra COUNT query is showing up, but it is among the queries I get from your overall code. I'm referring to the fact that the `select('id')` in the inner query doesn't seem to work, and all attributes are loaded regardless. When I run `Ship.select('id').includes(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name like ?', '%polly%')`, the generated SQL is `SELECT "ships"."id" AS t0_r0, "ships"."name" AS t0_r1, ...` and so on for all the attributes of all the included models, and they are loaded into the returned objects.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? I'm in 3.2.13, and using the same A has_many B has_many C model setup you are.

Comment: I'm on 3.2.13. I generated a fresh app with the exact Ship/Pirate/Parrot models I used in the example, to make sure the issue wasn't specific to my models. One thing I did notice was that the SQL generation was different when there were no records created yet (actually, the SELECT COUNT might be an optimization for that case).

Comment: Ah. Well, how about replacing the #includes with a #joins? A hint that the select overrides in the other case but not this one is the console complains unless I alter the select statement too: `Ship.includes(pirates: :parrots).where('ships.id IN (?)', Ship.select('groups.id').joins(pirates: :parrots).where('parrots.name LIKE ?', '%polly%'))`

Comment: Guess my example was insufficiently complex! Okay, suppose we have instead `Ship.includes(pirates: [:parrots, :peg_legs]).where('parrots.name LIKE ? OR peg_legs.name LIKE ?', ...)`. An inner join doesn't work in this case because the results would exclude pirates with no peg legs even if they had a parrot that matched the query, and vice-versa. (this is a user-facing search feature, so I can't know which models/attributes the search is intended to apply to)